# how can i allocate more space into Solana program in order to upgrade?

Tags: deployment, upgrade, solana, solana-transaction-instruction

When i try to upgrade a solana program on mainnet using buffer, it has limits because when you deploy a program on Solana, the amount of space allocated for that program is 2x the original program size. so in each upgrade we need more space in the origin program.

when size limit reaches, it threw an error:
`Program returned error: "account data too small for instruction"`

is there any way to allocate more space to the original program or any other way so i can upgrade my program as much as i need.
**PS: i won't deploy it again in order to upgrade.**

Answer (score 3):

Currently you cannot increase the account size. This is a known issue that will be fixed in `1.11` https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/26385